# How to interpolate and extrapolate non-monotonic vector data set in Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, extrapolation

I have a geographically distributed data set with X-coordinate, Y-coordinate and corresponding target value of interest D. That is, my data set consists from three vectors: **X, Y, D**.

Now what I would like to do, is interpolate and extrapolate the target variable D over a coordinate grid of interest. The `griddata`-function in Matlab seems to be able to help me in this problem, but it only does interpolation over the convex hull determined by my data set.

What I would like to do, is to also extrapolate the data D to any rectangular coordinate grid of interest like so:

[image]

I have tried using functions like `interp2` and `griddedInterpolant`, but these functions seem to require that I provide the known data as monotonic matrices (using e.g. `meshgrid`). That is, if I have understood correctly, I must provide **X,Y,D** as 2D-grids. But they are not grids, they are non-monotonic vectors.

So how can I proceed?

Comment: `griddata` and then `interp2` on the regular output of `griddata`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I will try that, thank you :)

Comment: @AnderBiguri unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. Maybe a MWE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out one way using `scatteredInterpolant`:

```
xy = -2.5 + 5*gallery('uniformdata',[200 2],0);
x = xy(:,1);
y = xy(:,2);
v = x.*exp(-x.^2-y.^2);
F1 = scatteredInterpolant(x,y,v, 'natural');
[xq,yq] = ndgrid(-5:.1:5) % Make the grid
vq1 = F1(xq,yq); % Evaluate function values at grid of interest
surf(xq,yq,vq1)
hold on
plot3(x,y,v, 'ro', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'red')
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
zlabel('V')
title('Interpolation and exrapolation based on scattered data')
```

[image]

The problem is, you can do extrapolation with only three methods: '`linear`', '`nearest`', '`natural`'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [griddata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) with option `'v4'` that uses biharmonic spline interpolation.

> Unlike the other methods, this interpolation is not based on a triangulation.

Other option is using [scatteredInterpolant](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant.html). You can choose to use any of `'linear'` or `'nearest'` methods for extrapolation

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try :)